# Revit API wall Thickness using Revit api 2020

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell

I am working at revit api to get walls of special room this is the part i have completed with Projecting rays technique. This is the main point that i am unable to do **Wall thickness**. Is there any way i can extract wall thickness. i am using revit 2020.
Thank you

Comment: This is the Solution:

hi, First Happy New Year :slight_smile:

Here “g” is the selected Element and 304.8 converts the feet in to mm. Here is the pickObject
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/0315fd62-b533-1817-2f2d-d9ebd4bc8e33.htm

             Wall onewall = g as Wall;
   
          double halfthickness =304.8 * onewall.WallType.Width;   
   
   TaskDialog.Show("Information","Wall Name : "+onewall.Name+" Thickness :"+halfthickness.ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, very easy.

Use the [`WallType` `Width` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/4333bb52-36aa-3514-e6cc-3bc53f6134e5.htm).

You could very easily have answered this question by yourself, either by searching the Internet or by [exploring the wall and its properties using RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup).

Please perform some minimal research for yourself before asking a question and making others do the work for you.

Here is some more [advice on researching how to solve a Revit API programming task](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3).

Comment: ah Thank you sir . this is really kind of you. the main problem was , i was not multiplying my wall width with 304.8 this was the main ingredient to convert my wall value to mm :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the wall width via the WallType of the wall.

On top of that, Revit will give you the width in its native unit (usually the imperial system). It is possible to convert it easily with the UnitUtils class. [Documentation here](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/128dd879-fea8-5d7b-1eb2-d64f87753990.htm)

The first step is to get the WallType. To do that, you have to retrieve the type ElementId via *GetTypeId()*, then the element via *document.GetElement()*, and finally cast it to WallType.

From the type, we obtain the width in Revit native units, which we convert into milimeters via the UnitUnits class.

Here is a code snippet:

```
        WallType wallType = document.GetElement(wall.GetTypeId()) as WallType;
        double nativeWitdh = wallType.Width;
        double milimeterWidth = UnitUtils.ConvertFromInternalUnits(nativeWitdh,DisplayUnitType.DUT_MILLIMETERS);
```

Best regards,
François

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.